# Python: iterating over tuples in list

Tags: python

right now I have code that is giving me this output:

```
[('KOR', [3, 1, 0]), ('ITA', [1, 0, 0]), ('TPE', [0, 1, 1]), ('CHN', [0, 1, 0]), ('JPN', [0, 1, 0]), ('AUS', [0, 0, 1]), ('GBR', [0, 0, 1]), ('UKR', [0, 0, 1])]
```

but it needs to be in this form:

```
['KOR 3 1 0', 'ITA 1 0 0', 'TPE 0 1 1', 'CHN 0 1 0', 'JPN 0 1 0', 'AUS 0 0 1', 'GBR 0 0 1', 'UKR 0 0 1']
```

How do I change the data into the correct form? I have been trying to iterate through the elements, but the closest I've gotten is

```
['KOR', 3, 1, 0, 'ITA', 1, 0, 0, 'TPE', 0, 1, 1, 'CHN', 0, 1, 0, 'JPN', 0, 1, 0, 'AUS', 0, 0, 1, 'GBR', 0, 0, 1, 'UKR', 0, 0, 1]
```

by using this code

```
for item in alist:
    for x in item:
        answer.append(x)

for item in answer:
    if type(item)==str:
        answer2.append(item)
    else:
        for f in item:
            answer2.append(f)
return answer2
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I miscopied the proper output form

Answer (score 1):

Provided the same structure, you can easily unwrap it within list comprehension by joining the two indices of each inner list:

```
data = [('KOR', [3, 1, 0]), ('ITA', [1, 0, 0]), ('TPE', [0, 1, 1]), ('CHN', [0, 1, 0]),
        ('JPN', [0, 1, 0]), ('AUS', [0, 0, 1]), ('GBR', [0, 0, 1]), ('UKR', [0, 0, 1])]

flattened = [" ".join(str(e) for e in [item[0]] + item[1]) for item in data]
# ['KOR 3 1 0', 'ITA 1 0 0', 'TPE 0 1 1', 'CHN 0 1 0', 'JPN 0 1 0', 'AUS 0 0 1',
#  'GBR 0 0 1', 'UKR 0 0 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a list comprehension, your original code could be changed as follows:

```
answer = []
for item in data:
    result = item[0]
    for x in item[1]:
        result = result + ' ' + str(x)
    answer.append(result)
return answer
```